# Call CSV Data and Startup VM's depending on State

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am very new to Powershell and I am wanting to write a script that will check the status of Virtual Machines i.e running or stopped, then when the host machine reboots depending on the status of the VM's pior the the reboot it will start them or keep them in a stopped state.

So far I have written a script that will auto start all the local VM's on the host machine on start-up, however sometimes we shutdown a VM for a reason and don't want it starting back up again.

I have started writing a script that captures all the VM's on a host and writes it to a CSV file:

Get-VM | select VMName, State, Uptime| Export-CSV D:\VM.csv -NoTypeInformation

This produces the VMName and the current state ie "Running" or "Off"

My plan is to have this script run via a task scheduler every 12hrs and on-start up have a ps1 script run and grab the VMName and State and depending on the data Start the VM if it was previosuly running, or keep it in a stopped state if the value was set to "off"

Is there an easy way to write this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the [tour]. Amongst other things, it will show you how to mark a question 'done' by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following article is helpful to you:
[Using Task Scheduler for PowerShell](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/)

You can find the documentation of VM PowerShell CMDLET at [VM PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/start-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

So for example if you have CSV file (vmstatus.csv) with VM Name and VM Status like:

```
VMNAME,VMstatus,
vm1,1
vm2,0
vm3,1
```

then maybe you can restart VM where the status is zero

```
$statusresult = Import-Csv -path C:\temp\vmstatus.csv
foreach ($st in $statusresult){
if ($St.VMSTATUS -eq 0){
Start-VM -Name $st.VMNAME
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have Task Scheduler setup so that it run my PS script, just need to know how to write a script that will turn a VM on depending on the value from the output of the CSV file

Comment: @ChrisGiles Okay I have updated my reply, maybe that can help a little! I am also PS novice though :)

Comment: Great thanks, Will give it ago!

Comment: At line:3 char:21
+ if ($St.VMSTATUS -eq Running){
+                     ~                      ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:6 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: @ChrisGiles so you can change the path Import-Csv -path D:\VM.csv also change the name of the headers name per your csv (e.g. $St.VMSTATUS and $st.VMNAME put your headers after $st.)

Comment: This is what I've Put:

$statusresult = Import-Csv -path D:\vm.csv
foreach ($st in $statusresult){
if ($St.VMSTATUS -eq Running){
Start-VM -Name $st.VMNAME
}
}

Comment: $statusresult = Import-Csv -path D:\vm.csv
foreach ($st in $statusresult){
if ($St.State -eq off){
Start-VM -Name $st.VMNAME
}
}

I have updated the $st.VMState to "state" I assume this has to match the header in the CSV file

Comment: @ChrisGiles I guess ($St.VMSTATUS -eq Running) should be ($St.VMSTATUS -eq 'Running') if you want to restart VM already running if you want to restart those which are "not running" then you have to use -ne operator, Yes it has to match to your CSV headers, also you may need to use quotation mark '' if you are using non numeric value

Comment: Ah, got it working!


$statusresult = Import-Csv -path D:\vm.csv
foreach ($st in $statusresult){
if ($St.State -eq 'Running'){
Start-VM -Name $st.VMName
}
}

Comment: @ChrisGiles Glad to hear that it is running :)

Comment: @ChrisGiles can you mark the question as "answered" please, maybe?